# Statistics are not updated in Open Source Ads list?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, statistics, open-source

I would like to know how frequently the statistics in the [Open Source Ads list](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/all) are updated.

Because some of the ads show that they are up for 3 days for a long time and some ads do not show statistics at all.

It looks like they are not refreshed at all.

Anybody?

**Edit:** Seems that statistics are not updated again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue with the scheduled task that updates the statistics - this has been fixed.

Thank you for reporting this!

Comment: It looks like that statistics update and stopped once again. For a long time they are not updated

Comment: @Artyom - the task that updates the statistics runs at 16:15 PST each day; I'll monitor it today to ensure everything is working correctly.

Comment: @Artyom - the votes were correctly updated after the task ran.

Comment: I'm not talking about votes but rather about click/view statistics and how many days ads are up. They seems to not being updated

Comment: @Artyom - you are correct, sir; fixing.

Comment: @Artyom - the stats are now updating.  Thanks again!